# How to extract inbox mail from Office 365 in Android?

Tags: android, office365

I followed this http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC373 demo,
 Here everything gonna correct, but he used Office base sdk for importing projects but its not available when i expand this sdk.

Please see the following image you will understand what i am talking about.

In this video, 
[image]

But when i expand its not available,
  [image]

Why?? what should i need to do??

Answer (score 0):

The video you referenced dates back to the SharePoint conference in March 2014. That was the Android SDK Preview. In October 2014, we took it out of preview and into general availability, and in the process made a few changes. For example, we developed the SDK to take advantage of Gradle to manage dependencies. Please follow the readme below:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android

Or, follow along with a sample that uses Eclipse ADT:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Android-Start